# How to format a DateTime object so it shows 24:00 instead of 00:00 in PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, date-formatting

I have a PHP program that shows two `DateTime` (or `DateTimeImmutable`) objects: `start` and `end`. To be human readable, midnight should be displayed as `00:00` for `start` but `24:00` for `end`.

Example:

```
$start = new DateTime('2017-01-01T22:00:00');
$end   = new DateTime('2017-01-02T00:00:00');
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i';
$startString = $start->format($format);
$endString   = $end->format($format); // What to do here instead?
printf("From %s to %s.\n",  $startString, $endString);
```

Actual output:

```
From 2017-01-01 22:00 to 2017-01-02 00:00.
```

Wanted output:

```
From 2017-01-01 22:00 to 2017-01-01 24:00.
```

I'm looking for a solution that works for any `$format` string, that is, I don't want a separate solution for each date format that occurs in the application.

Comment: There is no way to achieve this using any of the format specifiers, so you will have to write your own function/method in some place or other.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with. The idea is to replace 'H' in the format string with '24', but keeping everything else as-is.

```
<?php
function endFormat($dateTime, $format)
{
    $d = DateTimeImmutable::createFromMutable($dateTime);
    if ($d == $d->setTime(0, 0)) {
        $yesterday = $d->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        $format24 = str_replace('H', '24', $format);
        return $yesterday->format($format24);
    } else {
        return $d->format($format);
    }   
}   

$start = new DateTime('2017-01-01T22:00:00');
$end   = new DateTime('2017-01-02T00:00:00');
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i';
$startString = $start->format($format);
$endString   = endFormat($end, $format); 
printf("From %s to %s.\n",  $startString, $endString);
```

Output:

```
From 2017-01-01 22:00 to 2017-01-01 24:00.
```

Comment: `if ($dateTime->format('His') == '000000') {` or just `if (! $dateTime->format('His'))`

Comment: @splash58 That was indeed my first idea, but does this also work for milliseconds, microseconds, etc.? This is important, because e.g. `00:00:00.1` must *not* be displayed as `24:00:00.1`

Comment: If your aim is to make it human readable then why not use names of days, months etc? Or even 12 hour clock? 01-01 24:00 is more ambiguous than 01-02 00:00 to me.